# Cocos2d Collision Detection model - best for my case?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, box2d

I'm building a cocos2d iPhone game with lots of bullets and moving enemies and I'm detecting collisions between them. Every sprite can be represented by a circle for collision purposes. I'm considering the following options:

**1) Simple Sphere Detection**

I detect like this at regular intervals:

```
-(BOOL) isCollidingSphere:(CCSpriteExt*) obj1 WithSphere:(CCSprite *) obj2
{
    float minDistance = obj1.radius + obj2.radius;
    float dx = obj2.position.x - obj1.position.x;
    float dy = obj2.position.y - obj1.position.y;
    if (! (dx > minDistance || dy > minDistance) )
    {
        float actualDistance = sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );
        return (actualDistance <= minDistance);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**2) Box2d for collision detection only**

I create a Box2d body for all sprites as shown in this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone

My question is simple: If my priority is optimisation, which approach is faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is distance/radius based collision checks, you don't need a physics engine.

You should get rid of the **sqrt** though. First of all, you're using the square root function that works on doubles. For the float version use **sqrtf**.

To get rid entirely of the square root, make sure your objects store their radius squared (radiusSquared = radius * radius). That way you don't have to take the square root anymore:

```
-(BOOL) isCollidingSphere:(CCSpriteExt*) obj1 WithSphere:(CCSprite *) obj2
{
    float r1 = obj1.radius;
    float r2 = obj2.radius;
    float minDistanceSquared = r1 * r1 + r2 * r2 + 2 * r1 * r2;
    float dx = obj2.position.x - obj1.position.x;
    float dy = obj2.position.y - obj1.position.y;
    float actualDistanceSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
    return (actualDistanceSquared <= minDistanceSquared);
}
```

Comment: Your code example is incorrect: minimum distance = r1 + r2, minimum distance squared = r1*r1 + 2*r1*r2 + r2*r2, NOT r1*r1 + r2*r2. If you store radiusSquared, you still need 2*r1*r2 which is why your idea is wrong. (I'm not sure about sqrtf, I'm not an Objective C programmer, but I can see the bug in your code and your idea of storing squared radiuses is just wrong, so -1 from my part.)

Comment: Why is the idea of storing the squared radius wrong? Sqrt is a costly function and this reduces the need of it.

Comment: Oh wait sorry because you need 2*r1*r2, I get it.

Comment: Storing the radius squared is indeed a bad idea, I fixed the code to correctly calculate minDistanceSquared. I also forgot dx/dy. The code should still be faster than using sqrtf although that would have to be tested on a real device.

Comment: LearnCocos2D, I'm glad to remove that nasty -1 from your post.

Comment: LearnCocos2D: You are right about your updated optimisation, your operations only has a constant complexity, while sqrt is a function with a linear complexity.